# Get path of (custom) auxiliary file when `-output-directory` flag is given to pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, latexmk, auxiliary-files, knitr, write

## In short:

Say the following is built using `pdflatex -output-directory=tmp`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newwrite\fileHandle
\immediate\openout\fileHandle=outfile.csv
\immediate\write\fileHandle{hello world}
\closeout\fileHandle
\begin{document}
    ...
\end{document}
```

Now the file `outfile.csv` is in the `tmp` directory.

How can I, using LaTeX only, access the path (considering the `-output-directory`) of `outfile.csv`?

---

## Motivation and end goal:

We're making something along the lines of [`knitr`](https://yihui.name/knitr/), just for python.

A file, let's call it `outfile.csv`, is made by `LaTeX` using `\newwrite`. Now, I want `LaTeX` to run a command via `\write18` to process this file.

The problem is that if it's run with e.g. the `-output-directory` flag from `pdflatex` (or `latexmk`) the path to this file is not the same as the `.tex` file.

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
% Open a write filehandle
\newwrite\fileHandle
\immediate\openout\fileHandle=outfile.csv
%^ I need the absolute path (or a path relative to this .tex file) to outfile.csv
\newcommand\writeLine[1]{
    \immediate\write\fileHandle{#1}
}
\newcommand\processCSV[1]{
  % This now creates a file called pathtooutfile
  % (Just a dummy operation. In production would be a call to a software
  % that actually processed the file).
    \immediate\write18{echo #1 > pathtooutfile}
}
\AtEndDocument{%
    % Close CSV file
    \closeout\fileHandle
    % Now, process CSV file, but I need the path!
    \def\pathToOutfile{}
    % \pathToOutfile should contain the actual path to outfile.csv.
    \processCSV{\pathToOutfile}
}
\begin{document}
    % Write some arbitrary lines
    \writeLine{comma,separated,value}
    \writeLine{more,separated,value}
    Hello!
\end{document}
```

Now, assume this file is run using `pdflatex -output-directory=tmp/`, then I want the file `pathtooutfile` (that is the `\pathToOutfile` command) to contain `tmp/outfile.csv` or `/absolute/path/to/outfile.csv`. Can this be achieved?

Comment: not so helpful comment, but: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432428/texmaker-how-to-use-filename-as-the-output-directory-for-pdflatex#comment1083772_432428

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So you're saying that you shouldn't use the `-output-directory`-option? I use it by default with `latexmk` and haven't had any problems.

Comment: It causes a lot of problems for maintainers of tools like latexmk to keep things working even if it seems to work Ok as a user. It's at best a cosmetic feature and it vastly complicates the entire tex tool chain, it's a shame it got added.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I can see that. But it's still there, and now I have to, as you say, develop the software around it. I wish I could access it somehow! Like `pdftex` could make a macro like `\jobname`  but `\outdir` or something.

Comment: if the user is calling some wrapper program latexmk or your own python script  or anything else that handles the arguments, you can save the output directory (or any other command-line flags) in the environment and pick them up as needed. if you need to allow the user to call pdflatex directly on the commandline and then from within tex work out where the output is going then it's ... harder.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But can't the developers of `pdflatex` do something? I can't imagine it's that much work to implement some form of communication of command line args?

Comment: pdftex is more or less frozen anyway, I thought I might see it in the Lua tex status table in luatex, but no, and to be generally accessible from latex would also need to be in xetex and ptex as well. Anything is possible but tex's famous stability has some costs......

Comment: You could do this by invoking pdflatex by something like `pdflatex -output-directory=output '\def\OUTDIR{output/}\input{texfile}'`. This would give you a TeX variable \OUTDIR with the information you need. A command line like this can be configured in latexmk.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle As the latexmk maintainer, I actually like the -output-directory option a lot, and use it regularly. It didn't actually take much work to get latexmk to support it (with the main complication being about bibtex). But such things are a matter of opinion and preferred workflow.

Comment: @JohnCollins I apologise on speaking on your behalf:-)

Comment: @JohnCollins I need to know it without the user specifying it like that (just access it in LaTeX as long as it's built). Also, for the recorrd, I use the `-output-directory` a lot too, and in the [atom](http://atom.io) package for LaTeX, it's a setting that's easily settable!